# Никак не получается вывести результат.Не завершается цикл

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
    int c = scanner.nextInt();
    int localMin = 0;
    while (a != -1 | b != -1 | c != -1) {
        if (a > b && b < c) {
            localMin++;
        }
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Количество локальных минимумов - " + localMin);
}
```

}

Comment: А почему он должен завершиться?

Comment: @Igor При вводе -1 должен завершиться

Comment: А где Вы написали что Вы вводите?

Comment: @Igor В условии цикла написано пока одно из чисел не будет равно -1

Comment: Эта палочка `|` - что означает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае для выхода из цикла, если *одно из чисел не равно -1* оператор логического ИЛИ `||` должен использоваться в *отрицательном* условии:

```java
while (!(a == -1 || b == -1 || c == -1)) {
//..
}
```

которое можно переписать по законам де Моргана `NOT (A OR B) = NOT (A) AND NOT(B)` через логическое И `&&`

```
while (a != -1 && b != -1 && c != -1) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Все равно не завершается программа

Comment: это не побитовое сложение

Comment: @АнтонМихайлов Эта палочка `|`- что означает

Comment: @Igor это Логическое ИЛИ

Comment: @АнтонМихайлов Очень хорошо. Теперь человескими словами скажите Ваше условие.

Comment: Две условное ИЛИ

Comment: Да, не заметил классические грабли с отрицанием :)

Comment: @АнтонМихайлов, `|` - побитовое ИЛИ, `||` - логическое ИЛИ

Comment: @AlexRudenko спасибо,заработало.

Comment: побитовое ИЛИ с булевыми значениями тоже отработает, но лучше всё-таки в логических выражениях использовать логические операторы, так как у них есть "короткое замыкание" (short-circuit)